# On React, how can I call a function on component mount on a functional/stateless component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this functional/stateless component where I have a function `filterByCardinalPoint` which I need to call when component is mounted.
Is there a way to do that without writing the component as a class?

```
const PassengersCircle = ({ navigationStore, passengersData }) => {
  const filterByCardinalPoint = () => {
    const passengersByCardinalPoint = filter('value');
    ...
  };

  return (...)
};
```

Comment: And why? Whats bad about a class?

Comment: More code and it looks cleaner as a stateless component. @JonasWilms but is there no way to do it I will write a class :)

Comment: Well React is moving over to hooks, see Tholles answer :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) hook to run a function when the component has been mounted. By giving it an empty array as second argument it will only be run after the initial render.

```
const PassengersCircle = ({ navigationStore, passengersData }) => {
  const filterByCardinalPoint = () => {
    const passengersByCardinalPoint = filter('value');
    // ...
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    filterByCardinalPoint();
  }, []);

  return <>{/* ... */}</>;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

There was no way to emulate lifecycles in functional components before the introduction to hooks in React. You could however use libraries like `recompose` which provided a way to have modular portion of react code as HOCs

However after the introduction of hooks in v16.8.0 you could make use of `useEffect` hook to emulate lifecyle like behaviour in functional component.

In order to execute useEffect callback only on initial render you provide an empty array as the second argument. Please refer the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) for more details

```
const PassengersCircle = ({ navigationStore, passengersData }) => {
  const filterByCardinalPoint = () => {
    const passengersByCardinalPoint = filter('value');
    ...
  };
 useEffect(() => {
    filterByCardinalPoint();
 }, [])
  return (...)
};
```